# Bootstrap Carousel not interactive

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I am trying to add a carousel on my website and am following the tutorials on w3 and bootstrap website itself. I am not able to make the carousel advance with the buttons on screen. I have even tried copy/pasting code straight from the tutorials with no success. The code for carousel is as follows

```
    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

On the screen I get the first image printed, but when I try to use the arrows to advance or try clicking the indicators at the bottom nothing happens. I am guessing my issue is with my indicators... but I am not able to see what is wrong.

Comment: More often than not it's an issue with how/what order you included your dependencies, i.e. bootstrap.css, jQuery, popper.js and bootstrap.js, in that order.  Also make sure the code lines up to the version you are using.

Comment: Also make sure this is the only thing in your HTML with the id of demo. I see a lot of problems coming down to people reusing IDs even though they can only be used once.

Comment: Perfect, I had my jQuery after the js import. Thank you!